# How to fork a plugin to avoid updates after modifications?

Tags: plugins

I have made some modifications on a plugin. While everything is now working as I like to have it, I am annoyed by the update notification.

How can I fork the plugin such, that it I'd not linked anymore to the repository, but still uses all the settings from the database?
Is it as easy as renaming only the folder and the php file, or there more required?

Thanks.

P.S.: license is GPL, so I think it is ok to do it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe renaming the plugin file/folder should be enough; if not, you can also edit the plugin info in the header of the plugin file and set the version to something unreasonably high. On the rare occasion I've needed to do this, I usually also update the plugin info to indicate that the plugin has been modified from the original (and why, if it can be quickly summarized).

The function that performs the update check against the WP.org API is `wp_update_plugins`. It doesn't appear to have any filters available to remove a plugin from being sent to the API server, but it is storing the results in a transient called `update_plugins` so I imagine you could hook into the `pre_set_site_transient_{$transient_name}` filter to remove your plugin from the list, which should eliminate the admin notification.

Comment: Thanks. I saw a plugin which supports filtering for all or certain plugins, but the page is already slow enough. I am gonna use the trick with the very high version number now, this is very simple.